# 70% of Postgres disk size is not data or indices

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a few tables in Postgres (12.7) database hosted with an Heroku hobby-basic plan (max size = 10GB).

Doing `heroku pg:info` reports 11GB of used disk, so I'd like to do something about it to avoid having problems soon.

Most of the tables are small but a big one I have to store job openings. It has about 500MB in size, with the `description` column being the biggest as well. There are a few indices as well that take about 3GB.

Checking table and index sizes (adapted the query from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67727882/5031446) SO answer) I see that there is 7.3GB of data that's not either data or indices.

```sql
df5icl8qkl5bs4=> SELECT
   relname  as table_name,
   pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid)) As "Total Size",
   pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(relid)) as "Data Size",
   pg_size_pretty(pg_indexes_size(relid)) as "Index size",
   pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid) - pg_relation_size(relid) - pg_indexes_size(relid)) as "Remaining Size"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables 
ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(relid) DESC;


   table_name    | Total Size | Data Size  | Index size | Remaining Size 
-----------------+------------+------------+------------+----------------
 job             | 11 GB      | 453 MB     | 3373 MB    | 7385 MB
 location        | 15 MB      | 7144 kB    | 8392 kB    | 40 kB
 keyword         | 5480 kB    | 4648 kB    | 792 kB     | 40 kB
 company         | 5384 kB    | 3776 kB    | 1568 kB    | 40 kB
 biggest_cities  | 3344 kB    | 3336 kB    | 0 bytes    | 8192 bytes
 topic           | 80 kB      | 24 kB      | 16 kB      | 40 kB
 alembic_version | 56 kB      | 8192 bytes | 16 kB      | 32 kB
(7 rows)
```

What's up with those 7.3 GB? How can I free up that space?

Answer (score 2):

That must be the [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html) table, which stores overlength attributes out of line.

Answer (score 1):

You need [`pg_table_size`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html) instead of `pg_relation_size`. The second one is not a size of the table. To use `pg_relation_size`, you need to understand how data is stored in postgresql at a low level: relation `forks`, `toast`.

`pg_total_relation_size` provides correct size calculation including indexes. So the main difference is a separate TOAST table, which stores long columns.