# Show size of tables and other database objects in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, disk-space

I need to clear disk space, so I want to see which tables and other objects are using the most disk space in my Postgres databases.

Ideally, I'd like to see: database name, schema name, object type, object name and size in GB/MB.  I'm imagining something like the `du -h` command or the [`ncdu`](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/scr) utility but for Postgres.

Is there a command to do this in `psql`? I know about `\l+ {database name}` but this just gives me the size of the database, not the objects within it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [70% of Postgres disk size is not data or indices](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/298187/70-of-postgres-disk-size-is-not-data-or-indices)

Answer (score 1):

This is the hit list of the largest objects in your database:

```
SELECT oid::regclass,
       pg_relation_size(oid),
       relkind
FROM pg_class
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```